# Fixed decimal places / Java Groovy

Tags: groovy, decimal

How can I set a fixed number of decimal places for numerical values in Groovy?
Obviously that's easy for numbers with 4 decimals and more but what about this one? 
Example:

```
def num = 2.58 
return 2.5800
```

I would like to avoid turning those into strings.

Appreciate your help, thanks

Comment: Please provide a context, where you want to use them.  Have you looked at BigDecimal?

Comment: @cfrick I'm not going to use them anywhere further in the code. It is a user requirement that the outputs must be displayed with four decimal places. I have looked at BigDecimal, but as I understand, that class also cuts down the decimal places if there are zero's -it will never return  i.e 99.9900 (what I need) but 99.99

Comment: @User763733p, your question about number formatting. The simplest way is to use `String.format(...)`

Comment: thanks @daggett,  I was hoping to avoid strings but obviously it's not possible

Comment: You are asking about string representation of number. You could create own class and override toString method to show number in own way.

Comment: 2.58 == 2.5800 ... not sure what you're after if you're not talking about string representation....  You mean you want to round the numbers?

Comment: If you write `2.5000G` you get a BigDecimal, that has that scale set.  If you are doing calculations for accounting etc, where the 4 digits are important, use BigDecimal, set the scale properly etc. You only need to fall back to strings once you hit borders that can't handle such numbers (say, JSON).

Answer (score 2):

The normal way of dealing with decimal formatting in java/groovy would be the java [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) class. The following code:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat 

def num = 2.58

def df = new DecimalFormat("#0.0000")
def formatted = df.format(num)

println "formatted: ${formatted}"
```

gives the following output when run:

```
─➤ groovy solution.groovy 
formatted: 2.5800

─➤
```